# Maven assembly plugin, wrong dependency filenames

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am making an extra artifact in my maven build with maven-assembly-plugin (version 2.5.2).

Classpath is added to META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
<manifest>                                                                  
  <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
  <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
</manifest>
```

Dependencies are added in my assembly XML file:

```
    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
```

But the problem is that a given dependency is included in MANIFEST.MF as `name-1.2.0-20150413.094441-8.jar`. However the file copied to the "lib" folder is called `name-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

How can that be fixed, so the actual runtime classpath expressed in the jar manifest refers to actually existing files?

Comment: First please check the uptodate version of maven-assembly-plugin 2.5.3 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that there are two plugins that work not the same way regarding SNAPSHOTS.

The Maven Archiver is responsible for creating the MANIFEST. The best way IMHO is to force it not to use timestamped versions, setting its property  `<uniqueVersion>` to false. See [here for more detail](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/#class_manifest).

And I would let the assembly plugin work the way it works, with *-SNAPSHOT* instead of the timestamp.